# Questions about Fourier transform.

Tags: group-theory, fourier-analysis, representation-theory

I am reading the notes [Lecture notes on representation theory](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~kazhdan/).

I have some difficulty in proving a) in Exercise 1.2. We need to prove that 
$$
\mathcal{F}^2(f)(x) = qf^{-}.
$$

I compute as follows:
$$
\mathcal{F}^2(f)(x) = \sum_{y\in k} \bar{\psi}(xy)\mathcal{F}(f)(y) \\
= \sum_{y\in k} \bar{\psi}(xy) \sum_{z\in k} \bar{\psi}(yz)f(z) \\
= \sum_{z \in k} \sum_{y \in k} \bar{\psi}(xy)\bar{\psi}(yz) f(z).
$$

But why $\mathcal{F}^2(f)(x) = qf^{-}$? Thank you very much.